# How to delete a web app in orchard core after first setup?

Tags: .net-core, content-management-system, orchardcms

I am currently exploring OrchardCore CMS. I started a basic website using sqlite and dummy values for site name & admin setup. But now, i want to start over again from the website configuration set up page and maybe explore the saas option too. 
Is there any way to go back to the initial configuration page without deleting the base orchardcore cms solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to delete the site default in the App_Data\sites folder and relaunch the site.